# C/C++ : Why is it impossible to declare a pointer in loop initialization

Tags: c, loops, initializer-list, initializing

When printing an array, initializing an integer works.

```
int a[MAX_SIZE] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

for (int i = 0; i <= (MAX_SIZE - 1); i++)
{
    printf("%3d",a[i]);
}
```

However, I wonder why initializing a pointer to an integer ("walker") won't work:

```
int a[MAX_SIZE] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

for (int *aWalk = a, int *aEnd = a + MAX_SIZE - 1; aWalk <= aEnd; aWalk++)
{
    printf("%3d", *aWalk);
}
```

Comment: Please pick a single language. That said, the statement `int *aWalk = a, int *aEnd = a + MAX_SIZE - 1` wouldn't even work on its own, so it can't work in a loop header either.

Comment: `won't work` is a very bad problem description, FWIW.

Comment: What is the value of `MAX_SIZE`?

Comment: Remove the second `int` and it works fine: `int *aWalk = a, *aEnd = a + MAX_SIZE - 1;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement `int *aWalk = a, int *aEnd = a + MAX_SIZE - 1;` wouldn't even work on its own, so it can't work in a loop header either. The syntax you are looking for is this:

```
int *ptr1 = some_address, *ptr2 = some_other_address;
```

This works inside and outside of a loop. Also, note that your problem is not declaring one pointer but two. That's also why you are supposed to first extract a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` initial expression can be a definition for multiple variables as long as it is combined as a single definition:

```
int a[MAX_SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

for (int *aWalk = a, *aEnd = a + MAX_SIZE; aWalk < aEnd; aWalk++) {
    printf("%3d ", *aWalk);
}
```

Note that it is more generic to define the end pointer to point past the end of the array as this form can handle slices of width `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way only using pointer arithmetic. This is working because you are declaring an array of data and this data is continuously stored in the memory.

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

for (int *aWalk = a; aWalk < (a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(int)); aWalk++)
{
    printf("%3d", *aWalk);
}
```

Also try it here [IDE One[^]](http://ideone.com/4s6LM9).

**edit:**

due to the comments I changed the code using an end pointer. [code[^]](http://ideone.com/a1tO7L).

```
for (int *aWalk = a, *aEnd = (a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(int)); aWalk < aEnd; aWalk++)
{/*...*/}
```

Comment: I think the idea behind `aEnd` is to not evaluate the array size in every loop iteration (of course, in this case there's a good chance the compiler will optimize the calculation out.

Comment: @juanchopanza - Potentially incorrect.    This does not necessarily evaluate the array size in every loop iteration.  `sizeof` is a compile-time operator, so `sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)` is a compile time constant.    Since `a` does not change in the loop, a compiler might hoist the evaluation of `(a + sizeof(a)/sizeof(int))` out of the loop.    Whether it does that or not, is a concern of how well the compiler optimises.     Note, however, that this technique does not work if `a` is a pointer (which will happen if the array is passed as an argument to a function).

Comment: @Peter Which part is "potentially incorrect"? I said there's a good change the compiler will optimize the calculation out. It doesn't have to, but it can and it is likely it will.

Comment: The array size is `sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)` which definitely does not need to be re-evaluated on every iteration.   The end condition as a whole is more likely to be evaluated on every loop iteration than the array size.  Compilers tend to be pretty good at recognising when they are dividing two compile-time constants, and less so with recognising that larger expressions involving pointers are invariant.

Comment: @Peter So what? I don't really get your point. I know all of that. The whole point is about why OP chooses to use two initializers in the loop.

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra `int` in the second code. Also your placement of comma is wrong. Also removed unnecessary `aEnd` variable.

```
int a[MAX_SIZE] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

for (int *aWalk = a; *aWalk < (a + MAX_SIZE - 1); aWalk++)
{
    printf("%3d", *aWalk);
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure it was supposed to be there. Now `aEnd` is undefined.

Comment: IMHO 1st ';' is ',' and the last ',' is a ';' in the `for` line...

Comment: The placement of comma is correct in the question. Only the extra `int` is wrong.